# Enterprise Distribution "Unable to Download App" on iPhone 4 but works on iPhone5

Tags: ios, iphone, ad-hoc-distribution, xcode5.1, enterprise-distribution

I have a very interesting problem.  I have been through every post here on the "Unable to Download App" and I didn't see any that were specific to a version of iPhone.  I have an in-house app that has been distributed and is working on all iPhone5's.  However, when I try to install it onto an iPhone4s, I get the "Unable to Download App" error.  This tells me it's not a distribution file (.ipa or provisioning profile) problem, but something else?  I searched the console while trying to download the app and I don't see a single error.  I'm hoping someone can see something in here that I am not!

Here is the console log from an iPhone4S with iOS 7.1.2 while trying to install the application (fails):

```
Jul 25 11:47:57 iPhone itunesstored[105] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installing placeholder for Ashley.Sales.MarketMessaging
Jul 25 11:47:57 iPhone installd[63] <Notice>: 0x307000 handle_install_for_ls: Install of "/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.itunesstored/AppPlaceholders/5136889450095461532.app" requested by itunesstored
Jul 25 11:47:57 iPhone installd[63] <Notice>: 0x307000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app Ashley.Sales.MarketMessaging
Jul 25 11:47:57 iPhone installd[63] <Notice>: 0x307000 install_application: Installing placeholder
Jul 25 11:47:57 iPhone installd[63] <Notice>: 0x307000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Staging: 0.01s; Waiting: 0.00s; Installation: 0.09s; LS Sync: 0.00s; Overall: 0.11s
Jul 25 11:47:57 iPhone itunesstored[105] <Warning>: LaunchServices: updating placeholder for Ashley.Sales.MarketMessaging with icons
Jul 25 11:47:57 iPhone installd[63] <Notice>: 0x389000 handle_install_for_ls: Install of "/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.itunesstored/AppPlaceholders/5136889450095461532.app" requested by itunesstored
Jul 25 11:47:57 iPhone installd[63] <Notice>: 0x389000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app Ashley.Sales.MarketMessaging
Jul 25 11:47:57 iPhone installd[63] <Notice>: 0x389000 install_application: Installing placeholder
Jul 25 11:47:57 iPhone installd[63] <Notice>: 0x389000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Staging: 0.01s; Waiting: 0.00s; Installation: 0.09s; LS Sync: 0.00s; Overall: 0.10s
Jul 25 11:47:59 iPhone itunesstored[105] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Creating installProgressForApplication:LSApplicationProxy: Ashley.Sales.MarketMessaging (Placeholder) withPhase:0
Jul 25 11:47:59 iPhone lsd[77] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Updating installPhase for parent <NSProgress: phase=Loading; state=Waiting; fractionCompleted=0.000000> to 0
Jul 25 11:47:59 iPhone lsd[77] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installation failed for app Ashley.Sales.MarketMessaging
Jul 25 11:47:59 iPhone itunesstored[105] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: Ashley.Sales.MarketMessaging.Loading - <NSProgress: phase=Loading; state=Failed; fractionCompleted=0.000000> called, removing progress from cache
```

In contrast, here is the log from an iPhone5s 7.1.2 (works):

```
Jul 25 11:53:09 KFlynns-iPhone itunesstored[91] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installing placeholder for Ashley.Sales.MarketMessaging
Jul 25 11:53:09 KFlynns-iPhone installd[17] <Notice>: 0x10059c000 handle_install_for_ls: Install of "/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.itunesstored/AppPlaceholders/6505358839705877198.app" requested by itunesstored
Jul 25 11:53:09 KFlynns-iPhone installd[17] <Notice>: 0x10059c000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app Ashley.Sales.MarketMessaging
Jul 25 11:53:09 KFlynns-iPhone installd[17] <Notice>: 0x10059c000 install_application: Installing placeholder
Jul 25 11:53:10 KFlynns-iPhone installd[17] <Notice>: 0x10059c000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Staging: 0.01s; Waiting: 0.00s; Installation: 0.16s; LS Sync: 0.00s; Overall: 0.17s
Jul 25 11:53:10 KFlynns-iPhone itunesstored[91] <Warning>: LaunchServices: updating placeholder for Ashley.Sales.MarketMessaging with icons
Jul 25 11:53:10 KFlynns-iPhone installd[17] <Notice>: 0x10059c000 handle_install_for_ls: Install of "/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.itunesstored/AppPlaceholders/6505358839705877198.app" requested by itunesstored
Jul 25 11:53:10 KFlynns-iPhone installd[17] <Notice>: 0x10059c000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app Ashley.Sales.MarketMessaging
Jul 25 11:53:10 KFlynns-iPhone installd[17] <Notice>: 0x10059c000 install_application: Installing placeholder
Jul 25 11:53:10 KFlynns-iPhone installd[17] <Notice>: 0x10059c000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Staging: 0.00s; Waiting: 0.00s; Installation: 0.08s; LS Sync: 0.00s; Overall: 0.08s
Jul 25 11:53:10 KFlynns-iPhone itunesstored[91] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Creating installProgressForApplication:LSApplicationProxy: Ashley.Sales.MarketMessaging (Placeholder) withPhase:0
Jul 25 11:53:17 KFlynns-iPhone SpringBoard[16] <Warning>: Killing Ashley.Sales.MarketMessaging for app installation
Jul 25 11:53:17 KFlynns-iPhone itunesstored[91] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installing app for existing placeholder LSApplicationProxy: Ashley.Sales.MarketMessaging (Placeholder)
Jul 25 11:53:17 KFlynns-iPhone itunesstored[91] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Creating installProgressForApplication:LSApplicationProxy: Ashley.Sales.MarketMessaging (Placeholder) withPhase:1
Jul 25 11:53:17 KFlynns-iPhone lsd[75] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Updating installPhase for parent <NSProgress: phase=Loading; state=Waiting; fractionCompleted=0.550000> to 1
Jul 25 11:53:17 KFlynns-iPhone installd[17] <Notice>: 0x100484000 handle_install_for_ls: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/Downloads/6505358839705877198/7224552171467111663" requested by itunesstored
Jul 25 11:53:18 KFlynns-iPhone installd[17] <Notice>: 0x100484000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app Ashley.Sales.MarketMessaging
Jul 25 11:53:18 KFlynns-iPhone installd[17] <Notice>: 0x100484000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Staging: 0.89s; Waiting: 0.00s; Installation: 0.29s; LS Sync: 0.00s; Overall: 1.19s
Jul 25 11:53:18 KFlynns-iPhone lsd[75] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Updating identifier store
Jul 25 11:53:18 KFlynns-iPhone itunesstored[91] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: Ashley.Sales.MarketMessaging.Installing - <NSProgress: phase=Installing; state=Finished; fractionCompleted=1.000000> called, removing progress from cache
Jul 25 11:53:18 KFlynns-iPhone lsd[75] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installation ended for app Ashley.Sales.MarketMessaging
Jul 25 11:53:18 KFlynns-iPhone lsd[75] <Warning>: LSInstallProgress: In observeValueForKeyPath:userInfo.installState could not find parent progress for Ashley.Sales.MarketMessaging, it may have been removed
Jul 25 11:53:18 KFlynns-iPhone lsd[75] <Warning>: LSInstallProgress: In observeValueForKeyPath:fractionCompleted could not find parent progress for Ashley.Sales.MarketMessaging, it may have been removed
Jul 25 11:53:18 KFlynns-iPhone itunesstored[91] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: Ashley.Sales.MarketMessaging.Loading - <NSProgress: phase=Loading; state=Finished; fractionCompleted=1.000000> called, removing progress from cache
```

I will try anything at this point.  I just don't understand what is different.  I am hitting the exact same URL, it is being directed to the same d/l, even the console logs are almost exactly the same until the point the iPhone4s errors out.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: it really is a weird behavior,Can you try on an iPhone 4S with 7.1.1, I guess the version COuld be the only reason, there may be a bug in 7.1.2 as its a recent release ,You may have to ask Apple for help..

Comment: Are you hosting the file on https ? There as been a change some months ago between iOS 7.1.x ? (don't remember exactly version number). The new iOS version will not load from http, only from https !

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone! I am loading from https:// so I don't think that's the issue, but a good idea for sure.  

I was able to get a few of them working!  It seems they had an old Provisioning Profile still on their phone from about a year ago (it was going to expire in 3 days), so I had them delete that and retry the install and it worked!

Comment: did you find a solution as i have the same problem here with ios8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems they had an old Provisioning Profile still on their phone from about a year ago (it was going to expire in 3 days), so I had them delete that and retry the install and it worked!